# writing a variable to a file in a loop

Tags: file, python, io

I am writing a variable to a file in a for loop, and each time the variable has a new value.

```
for id in seqdata.keys():
    sequence=">%s\n%s\n" %(id,seqdata[id][seqindex])
    outfile.write(sequence)
```

The file is open and closed by the caller. This loop is in the function called. Sequence is overwritten in each iteration, will it overwrite the previous value written to the file or append it? Is there a better way to specify that each new value should be added into the file and not replace the old value?

Comment: Whether it will override or append the new value depends on how you opened the file. `'w'` mode means override while `'a'` mode means append. See https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files for more information.

Comment: I thought the write mode would overwrite the file, and append mode append the file. But I'm referring to what is written in one file over the iterations of the loop.

Comment: I am afraid the code segment you have given is not enough to understand your question. Can you provide more of the code?

Comment: This is the entire code inside one function. When the function is called in the main program, a file is opened in write mode, The loop iterates over the keys in a dictionary, formats the information in a variable, and writes it to a file. I'm trying to understand if what is written in the file can be overwritten when the variable takes on a new value, or if regardless of the variable having the same name the information written adds to what was written previously.

Comment: My understanding is that you want to update specific line(s) in your file if and only if that line(s) refers to a variable that has been updated. To the extent of my knowledge, I don't believe that there is a more efficient way other than what you are already doing.

Comment: I'm only asking whether, when the file is written to on each iteration of the loop, is what was written on the previous iteration overwritten, or is the new value of the variable added to what was in the file previously. And is there a different way to ensure that the value adds to the file instead of overwriting what was written by the same variable on the previous iteration.

Comment: Once you have opened the file, there is no overwriting. The file cursor moves along when you write to the file. The new string is added to the file. The only way that overwrite might happen is when you move the file cursor (e.g. using `f.seek()`). You can try this for yourself.